# How to except some element from collection Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-collection

I do request to Model:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id)->get();
```

And afetr try to except some fields from `$user` collection:

```
$user = $user->except(['surname', 'is_buyer', 'password']);
```

But in result I get still full `$user` collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you don't have here collection as you expect. You have here collection of models, so you will get all model fields. Also using:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id)->get();
```

is really strange, as you will get always 1 record and put this into collection.

Depending on your needs you might want to choose only some fields from database like this:

```
$user = User::select('id', 'name')->findOrFail($id);
```

instead of using collections here.

Comment: Yes, I need to except fields from model, but in controller, is model as collection? or not?

Comment: Model is not a collection.